I need to replace fascia, so I'm thinking of extending the roof
When I replaced my gutters recently, I found a section of fascia that needs to be replaced. I didn't have the time or material to do it then, but now I can. I also have a porch slab in my back yard, and I'm thinking I could just extend the roof pitch and cover the slab making a covered patio - since I'm taking the fascia off anyway, might as well upgrade the situation. I'm not sure of the best way to tie into the existing rafters/wall plate. I'm thinking I could just overlap against the existing rafters by a foot or so and fasten them together. Then they would all be parallel. I guess then the new fascia would be a bunch of smaller pieces and I'd have to be diligent about sealing them well. Anyone know of an illustrated guide to do this, or examples of work they've done? Looking online I see something similar but not exactly what I'm trying to do (keep same roof pitch and extend roof over patio).

Pictures will help.  Keeping the same roof pitch is maybe okay for low pitch roofs, but maybe a problem with high pitch roofs.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
